# Improve for loop efficiency

Tags: python, json, pandas, performance

I'm trying to convert 12,000 JSON files, containing event web data, into a single pandas dataframe.
The code is taking too long to run.
Any ideas on how to improve its efficiency?

Example of loaded JSON file:

```
{'$schema': 12,                       
 'amplitude_id': None,                
 'app': '',                           
 'city': ' ',                         
 'device_carrier': None,              
 'dma': ' ',                          
 'event_time': '2018-03-12 22:00:01.646000',                                
 'group_properties': {'[Segment] Group': {'': {}}},                         
 'ip_address': ' ',                   
 'os_version': None,                  
 'paying': None,                      
 'platform': 'analytics-ruby',        
 'processed_time': '2018-03-12 22:00:06.004940',                            
 'server_received_time': '2018-03-12 22:00:02.993000',                      
 'user_creation_time': '2018-01-12 18:57:20.212000',                        
 'user_id': ' ',                      
 'user_properties': {'initial_referrer': '',                                
  'last_name': '',                    
  'organization_id': 2},              
 'uuid': ' ',                         
 'version_name': None}
```

Thanks!

```
import os
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in os.listdir('path'):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    file_read1 = file.read()
    file_read1 = pd.read_json(file_read1, lines = True)
    data = data.append(file_read1, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the data looks like both in the file and in JSON format? It may be quicker to build one large json and then make it into a Dataframe. This method also can cause memory issues since it will create a new dataframe object 12,000 times.

Comment: Please edit that into your original question, comments aren't good for showing data or formatting

Comment: Yes, don't `.append` data-frames in a  loop. That is horribly inefficient. Create a list of data-frames and then use `pd.concat` on the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way of converting JSON strings to dataframes seems to be `pd.io.json.json_normalize`. Depending on the number of JSONs it is about 15 to >500 times faster than appending to an existing dataframe. It beats `pd.concat` by a factor of 13 to 170.

The side effect is that the nested part of the JSON (`group_properties` and  `user_properties`) gets flattened as well and that the `dtypes` need to be set manually.

Runtime for 12,000 JSONs (not taking disk I/O into consideration)

- append: ~177 sec
- concat: ~126 sec
- json_normalize: ~0.7 sec

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

data = []
for filename in os.listdir('path'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data.append(f)

# read one JSON and use it as a reference dataframe
df_ref = pd.read_json(data[0], lines=True)

# create a temporary dataframe, get its column 0 and flatten it via json_normalize
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data)[0]
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df_temp.apply(json.loads))

# fix the column dtypes
for col, dtype in df_ref.dtypes.to_dict().items():
    if col not in df.columns:
        continue
    df[col] = df[col].astype(dtype, inplace=True)
```

[image]

**Complete Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import time

j = {'$schema': 12,                       
 'amplitude_id': None,                
 'app': '',                           
 'city': ' ',                         
 'device_carrier': None,              
 'dma': ' ',                          
 'event_time': '2018-03-12 22:00:01.646000',                                
 'group_properties': {'[Segment] Group': {'': {}}},                         
 'ip_address': ' ',                   
 'os_version': None,                  
 'paying': None,                      
 'platform': 'analytics-ruby',        
 'processed_time': '2018-03-12 22:00:06.004940',                            
 'server_received_time': '2018-03-12 22:00:02.993000',                      
 'user_creation_time': '2018-01-12 18:57:20.212000',                        
 'user_id': ' ',                      
 'user_properties': {'initial_referrer': '',                                
  'last_name': '',                    
  'organization_id': 2},              
 'uuid': ' ',                         
 'version_name': None}

json_str = json.dumps(j)

def df_append():
    t0 = time.time()
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for _ in range(n_lines):
        file_read1 = pd.read_json(json_str, lines=True)
        df = df.append(file_read1, ignore_index=True)
    return df, time.time() - t0

def df_concat():
    t0 = time.time()
    data = []
    for _ in range(n_lines):
        file_read1 = pd.read_json(json_str, lines=True)
        data.append(file_read1)

    df = pd.concat(data)
    df.index = list(range(len(df)))
    return df, time.time() - t0

def df_io_json():
    df_ref = pd.read_json(json_str, lines=True)
    t0 = time.time()
    data = []
    for _ in range(n_lines):
        data.append(json_str)

    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(data)[0].apply(json.loads))
    for col, dtype in df_ref.dtypes.to_dict().items():
        if col not in df.columns:
            continue
        df[col] = df[col].astype(dtype, inplace=True)
    return df, time.time() - t0


n_datapoints = (10, 10**2, 10**3, 12000, 10**4, 10**5)
times = {}
for n_lines in n_datapoints:
    times[n_lines] = [[], [], []]
    for _ in range(3):
        df1, t1 = df_append()
        df2, t2 = df_concat()
        df3, t3 = df_io_json()
        times[n_lines][0].append(t1)
        times[n_lines][1].append(t2)
        times[n_lines][2].append(t3)
        pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
        pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1[df1.columns[0:7]], df3[df3.columns[0:7]])
        pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df2[df2.columns[8:16]], df3[df3.columns[7:15]])
        pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df2[df2.columns[17:]], df3[df3.columns[18:]])
    for i in range(3):
        times[n_lines][i] = sum(times[n_lines][i]) / 3
times  

x = n_datapoints

fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(x, [t[0] for t in times.values()], 'o-', label='append')
plt.plot(x, [t[1] for t in times.values()], 'o-', label='concat')
plt.plot(x, [t[2] for t in times.values()], 'o-', label='json_normalize')

plt.xlabel('number of JSONs', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('time in seconds', fontsize=18)
plt.yscale('log')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```